# Get union type of recursive property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

Suppose we have the interface:

```
interface Node<C extends Node[] = any[]> {
    children: C
}
```

Here, C is a generic that's a tuple that is the type of this node's children.

Let's define some nodes:

```
type Foo = Node<[]>
type Bar = Node<[Foo, Foo]>
type Baz = Node<[Bar]>
```

Baz is the root node. It is the parent of one Bar node, which is the parent of two Foo nodes. Foo has no children.

If I want to get the children of a node, I can do:

```
type TupleOfNodeChildren<N extends Node> = N['children'];
```

Here are some examples of this `TupleOfNodeChildren` type, which works as expected:

```
type T0 = TupleOfNodeChildren<Foo> // []
type T1 = TupleOfNodeChildren<Bar> // [Foo, Foo]
type T3 = TupleOfNodeChildren<Baz> // [Bar]
```

Now let's say that I want a type that is a union of every different type in the tuple. I can do:

```
type TypesOfNodeChildren<N extends Node> = TupleOfNodeChildren<N>[number];
```

And then of course our examples:

```
type T10 = TypesOfNodeChildren<Foo> // never
type T11 = TypesOfNodeChildren<Bar> // Foo
type T12 = TypesOfNodeChildren<Baz> // Bar
```

All of that works nice and fine. But what if I want something called `TypesOfAllChildren`, which is like `TypesOfNodeChildren`, but instead of just being a union of the immediate children, it is a union of **all** of the node's children?

This is how it would work:

```
type T20 = TypesOfAllChildren<Foo> // never
type T21 = TypesOfAllChildren<Bar> // Foo
type T22 = TypesOfAllChildren<Baz> // Bar | Foo    <--- Includes types of deep children
```

Notice that `T22` has both Bar, the immediate child of Baz, and then also Foo, which is the child of Bar.

I can't seem to get this `TypesOfAllChildren` type to work; it keeps complaining about a circular reference no matter what I try. I am assuming that you need some kind of recursion to get the types of all of the children, but I am not sure how to implement that without TypeScript complaining. [Here is a playground with these types and examples.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHsAmEA8BhZCAD0hEwGc0sIBtAXWQF5k4QBPegPmQG8AoZIOQIAFsAA2mKBBAAuZHj4BfPnzBsADigBi6dEyrYcXNZpQAhOFAMYjNXegA0yB3U6mtySwC8b1Y5ZQbqoA9CHIACpilADu6FAA1pQAVgCu5GDIMKAQAHTIAJKZaRnIAOYQYJRgIihgqRridWbI6DDINSgVINDACGgA5JSiElIyuR4oEQ1NAPIwthB4YpLSIDiohCQyFIYQ3MyoNAMjqzIDdADcquqeEQAMBtONEPOLy6NrOA7cYcj0k0iAEYnjNXgtqB8zutAr9wvY9M5XICIgBmUEvN6QlZjGFwbxw-6BOiqPh-KLAWLxJLIGIQcTiDp6fJFZAAIzg5D6cAZbHKlUocGQqRAwHQIFa7R5jLaHVqyA06HIXLZTWQIGoHTM5Amtym2qx2ChuI2W1Iu0WB0iYMNSxxX1QnBoIFSAFs2dArjcWhEgY9mBEDRCjfaZN89ISegA3aAooEggNB96hvFQQkOOMAJieSexnzDPkJgW9dyDAEEGcaHWadpRLQYQgAqZAAfjbyEbIWuKMz-si5crKfD6EjEBjUB7Cf7WnI8wr4irBas6b0PeziZnc8H+bxBOQfwcyAAPl4rEJkDgALTXwogBDiVLYarayXCFMlnT4vx2HzOHzBHt0Q3CBZxgedF3WbR8RXfQT0CY9T28IA)

**EDIT**:

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
type TypesOfAllChildren<N extends Node> = TypesOfNodeChildren<N> | TypesOfAllChildren<TypesOfNodeChildren<N>>;
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Recursively references itself
```

Adding an exit condition via a conditional type also doesn't work:

```
type TypesOfAllChildren<N extends Node> = TypesOfNodeChildren<N> | (TypesOfNodeChildren<N> extends never ? never : TypesOfAllChildren<TypesOfNodeChildren<N>>);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. So we have:

```
interface Node<C extends Node[] = any[]> {
    children: C
}

type Foo = Node<[]>
type Bar = Node<[Foo, Foo]>
type Baz = Node<[Bar]>
type Faz = Node<[Baz]>
```

And want to have a type that can get a union of all children, everywhere in the tree. I found that this works:

```
type SelfAndAllChildren<N extends Node> = N['children'][number] extends never ? N : {
    // @ts-ignore
    getSelfAndChildren: N | SelfAndAllChildren<N['children'][number]>
}[N extends never ? never : 'getSelfAndChildren']
```

Okay, so first:

1. There is a conditional that checks if the type of children is `never`, I.E. the node doesn't have any children. If that is the case, then we just return `N` and are done.
2. If there are children, then first we create a type that holds `getSelfAndChildren`. We need to do this because only the types of properties are allowed to recursively reference themselves -- union types can't.
3. The `getSelfAndChildren` property will include the node itself, `N`, and then the `SelfAndAllChildren` of the node's children. This is a recursive reference to `SelfAndAllChildren`, but because it's on the `getSelfAndChildren` property, TypeScript doesn't complain.
4. Lastly, we need to actually get the type of the `getSelfAndChildren` property. Unfortunately, TypeScript will complain about a recursive reference **unless we use a conditional type** to index the interface with `getSelfAndChildren` in it. So, we put in a conditional which will always return the type of `getSelfAndChildren` -- which itself has a recursive reference to `SelfAndAllChildren`.
5. Note the `@ts-ignore` above the `getSelfAndChildren`. If we were to pass in `any` to `SelfAndAllChildren`, that would throw an error. Putting the `@ts-ignore` silences the error on `any`, and the type defaults to `any`, which is what we want.

Please note that this is ["not recommended"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24016#issuecomment-428745727) because of its possible performance impact.

Also, here is a type that **just gets the children** in case you were looking for that:

```
type JustAllChildren<N extends Node> = SelfAndAllChildren<N['children'][number]>
```

And then [here is a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=18&pln=11&pc=5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHsAmEA8BhZCAD0hEwGc0sIBtAXWQF5k4QBPegPmQG8AoZIOQIAFsAA2mKBBAAuZHj4BfPnzBsADigBi6dEyrYcXNZpQAhOFAMYjNXegA0yB3U6mtySwC8b1Y5ZQbh46cL7Mtrg0PsEhyADKEOIwAIJkKeLieGKS0iA4qIQkMhSGENwRNADkohJSMlV0NCAArgC2AEbQDMSkpSAQAG7QyAD8aMjy-ELIAPSzyAACYOQAtMAA5iDo0gJCGxBgiclpmNl1efKFAD4JSanpmee5MgXVtS8gjc3tXUHuShohV6JUoA2G1nG4JG8iqByO91Oz3qXzoqnUngAKgBmAAMBmOD0wGSyORROG0YW48xcYWQtx89K8ViZDjiOIAjATEY9SRdXtCoNSFoL2diAEzck685F5HCsNjuZB8GnmdCtcjyDEodAwZAAKxa5DAyDAIhQHxRcQAUkawCTZa9gcUyJRIhU7tLiU8yXLUO9fQ0mq1Ot13OyACz45i240OwP5SneYXM3wMlm3BxAA) with everything.